# Why do I need kotest-framework-engine in the main sourceSets?

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotest

Through trial and error I've managed to setup `kotest` for a Kotlin Multiplatform desktop application, but I'm not quite sure I know what I'm doing. I thought that I need the test dependencies only in the `test` `sourceSets`, but when I don't include at least the `kotest-framework-engine` also in the `main`, the tests won't compile. Is this configuration as it should be or am I doing something wrong?

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val main by getting {
            dependencies {
                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kotest/kotest-framework-engine-jvm
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine-jvm:5.8.0")
            }
        }
        val test by getting {
            dependencies {
                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kotest/kotest-framework-engine-jvm
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine-jvm:5.8.0")

                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kotest/kotest-runner-junit5-jvm
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:5.8.0")

                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kotest/kotest-assertions-core
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:5.8.0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the project structure is:

```
my-project
   \src
      \main
         \kotlin
             \...
   \src
      \test
         \kotlin
             \test1.kts
```

where `test1.kts` is

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class Test1 : FunSpec ({
    test("is this a number") {
        "2".toFloatOrNull() shouldBe 2.5f
    }
})
```